# PHPStorm - Find and Replace Text in Selection?

Tags: phpstorm

In most other editors, I can select a portion of the text I want to run find and replace on and then hit the ctrl + h combination.  A screen pops up asking me what to find and what to replace.  How do I do this in PHPStorm?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using the Default keymapping (you can also use the keymaps for Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc) press `Ctrl+r` to show the Replace Toolbar. If you already have a selection then the option `In Selection` will already be checked, otherwise you can check it and then do your selection (if you select first and check the option second it will unselect the text after checking the option).

The feature is called `Replace` in the Keymap configuration if you wish to change the shortcut.

You can also press `Shift+F6` to directly rename variables if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

1. Highlight the code selection you wish to work on 
   ( you can use `alt + arrow up` if your looking for a cool way to do that)
2. Press `Ctlr + r` on PC or `Command + r` on a Mac
3. In the upper options window, insert the values you wish to replace
4. Select the "in selection" check box
5. Press Replace/Replace all button